# Maximize browser window with RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

Is there a way to maximize the browser window with RSelenium?

My current code is:

```
scrape_url <- "https://[...]"

eCaps <- list(firefoxOptions = list(
    args = list('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"')
))
    
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4546L, verbose=F, chromever="87.0.4280.20",
                              extraCapabilities = eCaps)
    
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(scrape_url)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the basic vignette the method is

```
remDr$maxWindowSize()
```

Found here: https://docs.ropensci.org/RSelenium/articles/basics.html#frames-and-windows-1